# Multi-tenancy in Golang

Tags: sql, go, multi-tenant

I'm currently writing a service in Go where I need to deal with multiple tenants. I have settled on using the one database, shared-tables approach using a 'tenant_id' decriminator for tenant separation.

The service is structured like this:

```
gRPC server -> gRPC Handlers -
                              \_ Managers (SQL)
                              /
HTTP/JSON server -> Handlers -
```

Two servers, one gRPC (administration) and one HTTP/JSON (public API), each running in their own go-routine and with their own respective handlers that can make use of the functionality of the different managers. The managers (lets call one 'inventory-manager'), all lives in different root-level packages. These are as far as I understand it my domain entities.

In this regard I have some questions:

1. I cannot find any ORM for Go that supports multiple tenants out there. Is writing my own on top of perhaps the sqlx package a valid option?
2. Other services in the future will require multi-tenant support too, so I guess I would have to create some library/package anyway.
3. Today, I resolve the tenants by using a ResolveTenantBySubdomain middleware for the public API server. I then place the resolved tenant id in a context value that is sent with the call to the manager. Inside the different methods in the manager, I get the tenant id from the context value. This is then used with every SQL query/exec calls or returns a error if missing or invalid tenant id. Should I even use context for this purpose?
4. Resolving the tenant on the gRPC server, I believe I have to use the UnaryInterceptor function for middleware handling. Since the gRPC 
   API interface will only be accessed by other backend services, i guess resolving by subdomain is unneccessary here. But how should I embed the tenant id? In the header?

Really hope I'm asking the right questions.
Regards, Karl.

Comment: 1. Of course, why wouldn't it be? 2. Is not a question. 3. Contexts are great for cancellation and terrible for data handling. 4. Header, parameter, however you want to do it. It's your design decision to make.

Comment: I've found `sqlx` to suit my project well. Just be aware of the design decision made such that fields returned from a query that are not mapped are considered "unused variables" and will throw an error. See the secondary documentation here under heading "Scan Destination Safety" http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I cannot find any ORM for Go that supports multiple tenants out there. Is writing my own on top of perhaps the sqlx package a valid option?

ORMs in Go are a controversial topic! Some Go users love them, others hate them and prefer to write SQL manually. This is a matter of personal preference. Asking for specific library recommendations is off-topic here, and in any event, I don't know of any multi-tenant ORM libraries – but there's nothing to prevent you using a wrapper of `sqlx` (I work daily on a system which does exactly this).

> Other services in the future will require multi-tenant support too, so I guess I would have to create some library/package anyway.

It would make sense to abstract this behavior from those internal services in a way which suits your programming and interface schemas, but there's no further details here to answer more concretely.

> Today, I resolve the tenants by using a ResolveTenantBySubdomain middleware for the public API server. I then place the resolved tenant id in a context value that is sent with the call to the manager. Inside the different methods in the manager, I get the tenant id from the context value. This is then used with every SQL query/exec calls or returns a error if missing or invalid tenant id. Should I even use context for this purpose?

`context.Context` is mostly about cancellation, not request propagation. While your use is acceptable according to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue) for the `WithValue` function, it's [widely](https://faiface.github.io/post/context-should-go-away-go2/) [considered](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/08/20/context-isnt-for-cancellation) a bad code smell to use the `context` package as currently implemented to pass values. Rather than use implicit behavior, which lacks type safety and many other properties, why not be explicit in the function signature of your downstream data layers by passing the tenant ID to the relevant function calls?

> Resolving the tenant on the gRPC server, I believe I have to use the UnaryInterceptor function for middleware handling. Since the gRPC API interface will only be accessed by other backend services, i guess resolving by subdomain is unneccessary here. But how should I embed the tenant id? In the header? [sic]

The gRPC library is not opinionated about your design choice. You can use a header value (to pass the tenant ID as an "ambient" parameter to the request) or explicitly add a tenant ID parameter to each remote method invocation which requires it.

Note that passing a tenant ID between your services in this way creates *external trust* between them – if service A makes a request of service B and annotates it with a tenant ID, you assume service A has performed the necessary access control checks to verify a user of that tenant is indeed making the request. There is nothing in this simple model to prevent a rogue service C asking service B for information about some arbitrary tenant ID. An alternative implementation would implement a more complex trust-nobody policy whereby each service is provided with sufficient access control information to make its own policy decision as to whether a particular request scoped to a particular tenant should be fulfilled.